# Struts relative path flattened in 7.0.78 but not in 7.0.79, breaking isNormalized

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, struts2, tomcat7

We're returning a @Result from a Struts 2 action in a Spring Boot app that specifies a location containing a relative path, in order to reference a jsp in a sibling directory to the root of the rest of the application.

```
@Result(name = "foo", location = "../../cat/bar.jsp")
```

This works in Tomcat 7.0.78, arriving in the StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest as:

```
ApplicationHttpRequest.requestURI = "rootParent/cat/bar.jsp"
```

In Tomcat 7.0.79+, this flattening is no longer happening, and when the request reaches StrictHttpFirewall to check for url normalization, it blows up because it arrives as:

```
ApplicationHttpRequest.requestURI = "rootParent/root/WEB-INF/../../cat/bar.jsp"
```

I've scoured the Apache 7 [changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html) and [security fixes](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-7.html#Fixed_in_Apache_Tomcat_7.0.79) to see if there is anything that might cause this to occur, but can find nothing. I've tried tweaking the **useRelativeRedirects** Context property, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Pulling my hair out stepping through filter chains in debug. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and found a solution.

The problem is that [this commit](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/fdd86cf2e0b851aced2f460c765fea5293a30940#diff-8b91a9296e19012bf6be4bdf975fab0d) changes the behavior of `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getRequestDispatcher` between 7.0.78 and 7.0.79. Previously, the provided URL was normalized before being appended to the context path. In 7.0.79 and beyond, the normalized version is no longer being used.

There are no settings that change this behavior, but I figured out how to resolve the issue by modifying the location Struts passes in. By the time the request reaches ApplicationContext, struts already has combined the context and url into a single location, but we can override the context portion in the Request annotation. It uses `"WEB-INF/content/" + "%{url}"` for everything else, so I changed it to just `"%{url}"`.

Before, results in "WEB-INF/content/../../bar.jsp"

```
@Result(name = "foo", location = "../../bar.jsp")
```

After, results in "bar.jsp"

```
@Result(name = "foo", location = "bar.jsp", params = {"location", "%{url}"})
```

Answer (score 0):

All those relative paths often show up in security vulnerability tools, so they aren't a great idea often, and you probably should stop using them.

That said if you are as stubborn as a mule, you can still use them, just not within the annotation itself, but you could use `static`  variables to achieve the same thing, given if those files exist as resources somewhere:

`FooBar.class.getClassLoader().getResource('../../cat/bar.jsp')`